# Exporting ag-grid from shared module to lazy loaded module giving error

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I have created sharedmodule, in which i am importing angular ag - grid.
So as per ag - grid's office site we have to write `AgGridModule.withComponents([])`  in `imports`.

But I have to export it as well, because I want to use this export as an import in one of my lazy loaded module and not directly in `appModule`.

But exporting of `AgGridModule.withComponents([])` from a shared module is giving me errors.

**shared.module.ts**

```js
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

imports: [
  AgGridModule.withComponents([])
]

enter code here`enter code here`

exports: [
  AgGridModule.withComponents([])    // this export is giving error
]
```

**Error description:**

> ```
> Type 'ModuleWithProviders<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
> Type 'ModuleWithProviders<any>' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more
> ```

Answer (score 8):

You are exporting it the wrong way. Export only `AgGridModule`. your code will look like this.

**shared.module.ts**

```js
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

imports: [
  AgGridModule.withComponents([])
],
exports: [
  AgGridModule    // without withComponents([])
]
```